# geom_histogram overlaying with Transparent Rectangle

Tags: r, histogram, annotate

I want to draw a histogram with background color. So I used geom_histogram + annotate ("rect") function. However, the color of histogram and annotate's rect is overlaying!
I don't want the interruption about the color...

[image].
[image]

```
  ggplot(fol, aes(x=dftime)) +  geom_histogram(aes(x=dftime, y=..density.., color=black) + annotate("rect", xmin=20, xmax=30, ymin=0, ymax=Inf, alpha=0.2, fill="red")
```

I don't want the color of my histogram affected by these annotate...
Is there any way to histogram forward to the rect by annotate?
I know I can adjust the alpha in annotate. But even though I changed it low (0.1~0.2), it still disrupt the color of histogram...

Comment: Wow now i found the answer. after using 'annotate', draw the histogram again.

Comment: Then, it perfectly works :)

Comment: If you found an answer then you can post the solution below. That is how Stack Overflow works. This is not a discussion forum, nor a personal help desk. If you found the answer on Stack Overflow, you can close your question with an answer from another question too